# Docraptor Page with background image

Tags: pdf-generation

Has anyone tried generating a pdf using docraptor and the pages will contain background image? I tried adding the image as css body background property but doesn't seem to work. Is it supported? If yes, please share how did you do it.
Thanks! :)
my html is something like below:

```
<body style='background:url(backgroundImage.png) center center'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer for DocRaptor. Background images are definitely supported.

Your issue is likely a lack of a base URL, so DocRaptor doesn't know where to find backgroundImage.png. See `baseurl` API parameter for more information: https://docraptor.com/documentation#api_baseurl.

DocRaptor support is also available to all customers to assist with debugging.